# End of string in C#

Tags: c#

Do strings end with a `\0` character when being stored in the memory? How does a compiler know the end ??

If it is true then

```
Console.WriteLine(str.LastIndexOf('\0'));
```

must return length, but the output is = -1

Comment: No.  A string has an array of characters and a marker of length, instead of being null-terminated like in C.

Comment: Zero terminated strings are often used in `C`, not in `C#`.

Comment: Which is why .NET strings have a 0 at the end, strings are heavily used in I/O and that takes an operating system call.  A C call.  The compiler is not involved, most string handling code is in the CLR and it takes care of getting the zero-terminator at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)

> Internally, the text is stored as a sequential read-only collection of Char objects. There is no null-terminating character at the end of a C# string; therefore a C# string can contain any number of embedded null characters ('\0').

Also, from Jon Skeet's [Strings in .NET and C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html)

> Although strings aren't null-terminated as far as the API is concerned, the character array is null-terminated, as this means it can be passed directly to unmanaged functions without any copying being involved, assuming the inter-op specifies that the string should be marshalled as Unicode.

In short, the internal char array does end with a `\0`, but the API (e.g., `LastIndexof`) ignores it.

Additionally, if you manually insert `\0` *in the middle* of a c# string (e.g., `Hello\0World`), the C# string API will ignore it, but other API's might not and end up ignoring everything past the first `\0` (e.g., `World`).

Looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0a17bbac4851d0d4.html)

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    //...
    Contract.Assert(src[this.Length] == '\0', "src[this.Length] == '\\0'");
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ok, if LastIndexOf ignores \0 then suggest me any method which confirms it's presence .

Comment: @SujeetKumar Again, the *whole* C# API ignores it. If you want proof you can either 1) look at the source code or 2) write a small C program that checks for the presence of the null-character, and call it from C# using P/Invoke. I've added a small part of the C# source code to prove strings end with a null-char.

Comment: You could just take our word for it.  If you want to see it then use the debugger, the Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1 window can show you.  Put the string variable name in the Address box.  Hard to distinguish from bytes that belong to padding or other objects however, a 0 doesn't exactly stand out, an object's syncblk is often 0.

Comment: It can also be easily checked by using `unsafe` code:
`fixed(char* p  = s)
            {
                char* c = p;
                int* lp = (int*)c;
                lp-=1;
                Debug.Assert(*lp==s.Length); // length before System.Char sequence
                c+=s.Length;
                Debug.Assert(*c=='\0'); // \0 after the end
                Console.WriteLine("Everything as expected!");
            }
`

Answer (score 2):

The `string` object contains the length of the string, this is how it knows where the end is.
Actually there is '\0' symbol at the end of string for unmanaged compatibility, but you can't access it from managed code.

Comment: And thus it is 'out of range' for `LastIndexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the beginning and end of the chain

```
       int last = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(" ", richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        last += 1;
        int first = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(" ",richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        first -= 1;
```